# Call Activity every 5 minutes in background when application kills

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-pendingintent

I don't know how to launch activity every 5 minutes by using services and broadcast receiver.
When i want to click on button start the service and it's call every 5 minutes and reopen my application if user can close application or kill process.For this which type of actions can i perform and what are the permissions can i take and which methods can i use.Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use timer task class as and call it every 5 seconds

```
class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ReminderTask is completed by Java timer");
        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myActivity.class);
        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);


    }
}
```

call to timer task as

```
    ReminderTask timer = new Timer();  //At this line a new Thread will be created
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), 5*1000, 5*1000); //delay in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got you right but creating an AsyncTask might help. This task could perform  an intent every x minutes.